# Unexpected scope of static anonymous function in PHP

Tags: php, static, scope, anonymous-function

I have the following code in PHP<sub>5.6.2</sub>. It has classes `Father`, `Guy extends Father` and `Child extends Guy`. All those classes have a static method `hi` which outputs the name of the class:

```
class Father {
  static function hi() {
    echo "Father" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

class Guy extends Father {

  static function hi() {
    echo "Guy" . PHP_EOL;
  }

  static function test() {
    self::hi();
    static::hi();
    parent::hi();
    $anon = function() {
      self::hi();  // shouldn't this call Guy::hi()?
      static::hi();
      parent::hi();  // shouldn't this call Father::hi()?
    };
    $anon();
  }

}

class Child extends Guy {
  static function hi() {
    echo "Child" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

Child::test();
```

The outputs I expect are:

```
Guy
Child
Father
Guy
Child
Father
```

The first three lines were as expected. But the last three surprisingly were:

```
Child //shouldn't this call Guy::hi()?
Child
Father //shouldn't this call Father::hi()?
```

So it seems that the anonymous function `$anon` has the scope of `Child`. But shouldn't it have the same scope as the method it was called in (i.e. `Guy`)?

---

**EDIT 1:** Also, wouldn't [the specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#anonymous-function-creation) require this to work as I expected:

> An anonymous function defined inside an instance or static method has its scope set to the class it was defined in. Otherwise, an anonymous function is unscoped.

---

**EDIT 2:** Note that when I remove the `static` modifier from `Guy::test()` and call it like `(new Child)->test();` the output is as expected.

---

**EDIT 3:** After expecting some even stranger behavior, I think this is an actual bug in PHP [-> according bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69007)

Comment: get a <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active on line <b>18</b><br /> if I execute your code

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't expect `::hi()` to be printed but to be called on another class (see edit)

Comment: @Freez I use http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ to test it using PHP 5.6.2

Comment: @Freez Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock I used 5.3.3 for my test (that's the issue ;), you didn't specified the version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

Child inherits function test(), so the anonymous function's scope is Child, which is "the class it was defined in".

Comment: Couldn't one say the exactly same thing about the case where `Guy::test()` is not static? And in this case it would still be handled as "defined in" Guy, even though being called through Child.

Comment: If Guy::test() is not static, then it is not "defined inside an instance or static method". But it is kind of hard to get your mind around all of the ins and outs.

Comment: Could you please share a link from the php.net manual or the php github specification that specifies this? Just so that I can learn from the root.